# Loading Dropbox dropin.js script in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, dropbox-api

I need to load this script in a Meteor project: 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="my-api-key"></script>`

I first tried to do a `$('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="my-api-key"></script>')` on Template.Image.onRendered, but the problem is that the library loads every time the template is rendered, and gives this error: `dropins.js included more than once`

I've also looked at the wait-on-lib package, https://github.com/DerMambo/wait-on-lib, but I'm not able to pass the data-app-key or id to the Router waiton function.

Do you have any suggestions on how to load this script?

Comment: Is it causing any functional issue? That "dropins.js included more than once" message is just a warning, and it will actually stop running the script at that point anyway, so the only harm that would do is the additional network call to load it. (And hopefully it should be cached anyway.)

Comment: You may be right that I can just ignore the warning, but Meteor does not seem to be able to view the button on the second render. I suspect that this has something to do with the routing setup.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used dropbox sdk, but maybe this help you or give some idea for that.

```
if(window.Dropbox){
    // Nice, is already loaded
}
else {
    $("head")
        .append('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="your-api-key"></script>');
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js';
    head.appendChild(script);
    script.onload = function(){
        //whatever, I Want It All!
    };
}
```

You can add this on your `Template.template_name.onCreated` code block.